# Can I make a Schengen Visa Appointment without having all the information for the application form?

Tags: visas, schengen

When you make a Schengen Visa Appointment in the UK, you have to fill in the application form online. I do not have all the required information yet. I would like to make the appointment asap. Can I make the Appointment and then change some information later? Does the information get stored on the system. I remember receiving a page with barcodes printed on with my previous appointment.
Thanks

Comment: No. Some fields are mandatory in the order to submit your application, and get your appointment.

Comment: @Rob What information are you missing?